# Thymeleaf iterating over a list

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I want to iterate over a list using thymeleaf. My code looks like this:

```
<ol th:each="test: ${tests}">
    <li th:text="${test.toString()}"></li>
</ol>
```

At this moment, tests Set contains 2 elements, which have a toString() representation, respectively test1 and test2

My output in html looks like this:

```
1.test1
1.test2
```

I am wondering why do both of them have the number 1, instead of 1 and 2?

Answer (score 2):

You are creating an ordered list for each item instead of listitems.

This should work:

```
<ol>
    <li th:each="test: ${tests}" th:text="${test.toString()}"></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: yup, now they are numbered 1 and 2, but in reverse order, like this: 1.test2, 2.test1

Comment: @TomekNowak - You can sort your Java list first. You can make your test objects comparable, or use a comparator. Some basic examples [here](How to use Collections.sort() in Java?), as a starting point.

Comment: Sets don't have a specified order... if you want an order, you should use a collection that guarantees an order.